# How to get rid of rouge "true" in Rmarkdown when setting toc: true in Front Matter

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, blogdown

Here's an example of my front matter in an Rmarkdown document.

```
---
description: "Exploring the depths of harmony starts with scales. Click 
on to learn every poossible functional scale in western music."
title: "Scales"
date: "2017-05-12"
draft: false
weight: 200
bref: "Harmony in music comes from scales. Each unique functional scale 
represents an opportunity for a triad that is surrounded by a different 
set of extensions or color notes."
toc: true
script: 'scales'
---
```

Problem is, the word "true" is showing up in my html output of the Rmarkdown. Any idea how to fix?

Let me know if you need more information, I have sort of a complicated set up going on using blogdown.

Comment: I don't understand the question. (Neither of the downvotes is mine.) I don't see an implied workflow for this file to produce output. Just because you cite [yaml] and [blogdown] does not affect the lack of clarity for my viewing. BTW the word "rouge` is a color.

Comment: Isn't the `toc:` option specific to certain output formats? For instance, `output:\n++html_document:\n++++toc: true` (replace `+` with spaces). Docs: [pdf](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#table_of_contents), [html](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#table_of_contents), and [md](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/markdown_document_format.html#table_of_contents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of adding a table of contents to a **blogdown** website is documented in [Section 1.5](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/output-format.html) of the **blogdown** book.

```
output:
  blogdown::html_page:
    toc: true
```